# run shell script with or without options

Tags: bash

I would like to run a shell script that will print either 'yesterday' or 'tomorrow' based on the option that is provided at the command line. If the option is -y, then the output should be 'yesterday', otherwise is 'tomorrow'. In addition I would like to add the option help -h which will print the syntax of the script.

I made the script as:

```
#! /bin/bash

h= y=

while getopt :f:vql opt
do
    case $opt in
    y) setday=true
    ;;
    h) tohelp=true
    ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if [setday=true]
    NAME=$yesterday
else
    NAME=$tomorrow
fi

if [tohelp=true]
    MSG=$'runner [-y]'

echo $NAME
echo $MSG
```

but when I run it, I simply get an infinite loop that prints

```
-- opt
-- opt
-- opt
etc
```

What I am getting wrong?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to find basic problems, such as missing spaces around `[`, `]` and `=`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

setday=false
tohelp=false

yesterday="Yesterday"
tomorrow="Tomorrow"

for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -y)
        setday=true
        shift
        ;;
    -h)
        tohelp=true
        shift
        ;;
esac
shift
done

if [ $setday = true ]; then
    NAME=$yesterday
else
    NAME=$tomorrow
fi

if [ $tohelp = true ]; then
    MSG='runner [-y]'
fi

echo $NAME
echo $MSG
```

Answer (score 0):

@itachi's answer looks good. Although, if you want to continue using getopts, this should also work:

```
#! /bin/bash

yesterday="yesterday"
tomorrow="tomorrow"
setday=false
tohelp=false

while getopts "yh" opt
do
    case $opt in
    y)
        setday=true
        ;;
    h)
        tohelp=true
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if $tohelp; then
    echo "runner [-y]"
    exit
elif  $setday; then
    NAME=$yesterday
else
    NAME=$tomorrow
fi

echo $NAME
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
tomorrow
$ ./test.sh -y
yesterday
$ ./test.sh -h
runner [-y]
```

Comment: thank you, both scripts worked perfectly and now I  have the usage clearer